# What are the attributes of hr tag in the HTML?

Tags: html

I want to ask the following things about the **hr tag** in HTML

1. What is the use of the hr tag?
2. What is the full form of the hr tag?
3. What are the attributes of hr tags in the HTML?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp

Answer (score 0):

1. The `<hr>` element is most often displayed as a horizontal rule that is used to separate content (or define a change) in an HTML page.
2. hr : Horizontal Rule
3. The `<hr>` tag supports the [Global Attributes in HTML.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp)